# Node JS & Apache HTTP

Tags: node.js, apache, proxy

Need help/suggestion on setting up an web application and REST api in server.

Currently there are 3 applications like as below

1. User web application - Running on node.js - port 3389 / universal react application
2. Admin web application - Running on apache - port 8080 / laravel
3. Rest Api for user application - Running on apache -  port 8080 / laravel

Currently we load the applications like as below

User Application:- 
www.xyz.com:3389
www. xyz .com:3389/help
www. xyz .com:3389/landlord-intro

Admin Application:-
www.xyz.com/app/admin

REST Api routes:-
GET http://xyz/app/country?id=1
GET http://xyz/app/location

For loading the user application without port number , we tried to set proxy pass in apach conf like as below

ProxyPass  http://127.0.0.1:3389/
ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:3389/

ProxyPass  http://127.0.0.1:8080/app/admin/
ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8080/app/admin/

Now the after restarting the apache , we are able to access user application without using port number but unable to access the admin application and also we need to know how to proxy pass rest API's from client.

Answer (score 0):

You can use or create virtual host ,In Apache HTTPD basically it would be like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName xyz.com
Redirect / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName example.com
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /path/to/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/key.pem
ErrorLog /path/to/logs/publicaname.example.com-ssl-error.log
CustomLog /path/to/logs/publicaname.example.com-ssl.log combined

ProxyPass /api/input http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/input
ProxyPassReverse /api/input http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/input
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: That we have done,it's mentioned in the post as well. One user application works but the other does not.

Comment: ' <Location / >
ProxyPass  http://127.0.0.1:3389/
ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:3389/
</Location>

<Location /app/admin >
ProxyPass  http://127.0.0.1:8080/app/admin/
ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8080/app/admin/
</Location>'
 This did not work. The user app opens fine which is www.xyz.com:3389  but the admin app: www.xyz.com/app/admin does not up